# How to reduce video bit rate from a webm file online for Android?

Tags: java, android, video

This webm video will not play on an android device because I THINK that the bit rate is too high. Looking at the supported versions on the Android Developer website, I think that the bit rate for this type of video (codec VP8) should be around 2 Mbps and it is at about 9 Mbps.

I have tried using FFmpeg but I have not had luck so far.

I don't need to store the video permanently on the phone because it is so short so I don't really need an output file.

I just need to take the video from the server, cut it down to about 2 Mbps, then play it with a VideoView/MediaController/MediaPlayer

Comment: I don't think rencoding the video on client side is a good idea. It will be quite long and energy intensive. I think it would be a better idea to handle it server side.

Comment: Also, have you tried the video on another phone/tablet or a desktop?

Comment: Hmmm I see. That makes sense.

Comment: I tried the video on 2 different physical devices and 2 different emulated devices and they don't work on all 4

Comment: Did you try on a PC, with something like VLC? If it don't work on that, the video file itself is bad and should probably go to the trash.

Comment: Yeah it works fine on a PC and on a browser